# Heads-Up notification stuck in full-screen mode after dismissal

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm seeing some strange behaviour regarding ongoing [heads-up notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up) that are backed up by a full-screen intent. Given two activities, `MainActivity` that contains only a button to display the notification:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL  = "TestChannel";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 2;

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        Button showNotification = findViewById(R.id.show_notification);

        ensureNotificationChannelCreated();
        showNotification.setOnClickListener(v -> notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification()));
    }

    @TargetApi(O) private void ensureNotificationChannelCreated() {
        if (SDK_INT >= O) {
            NotificationChannel incoming = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL, "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(incoming);
        }
    }

    public Notification createNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContentActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL)
                .setContentText("Test notification")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setFullScreenIntent(pi, true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And the Activity provided by the full-screen intent, `ContentActivity`:

```
public class ContentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);    
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

- If I click the button, then click the notification, I see `ContentActivity` and can repeat this process over and over.
- **However**, if I *swipe up* to hide the heads-up notification from view, then click the notification from the drag-down tray, any subsequent times I click the `showNotification` button `ContentActivity` is immediately displayed, and the heads-up notification *does not appear*.

I would like the heads-up notification to still be displayed on subsequent button clicks, even if a notification has previously been swiped upwards. Are there any additional flags or settings that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process which Android uses to choose a full-screen activity over a heads-up notification seems a bit opaque. [From the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#fullScreenIntent) (my bold):

> An intent to launch instead of posting the notification to the status bar.
>
> The system UI **may choose** to display a heads-up notification, instead of launching this intent, while the user is using the device.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation as to how this decision is taken. The only workaround I've found is to ensure that each notification is posted to the manager with a different ID. So in `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    showNotification.setOnClickListener(v -> {
         int notificationId = Math.abs(random.nextInt());
         notificationManager.notify(notificationId, createNotification(notificationId))
    });
}

... 

public Notification createNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", notificationId);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ...
}
```

And in `ContentActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

    int notificationId = getIntent().getIntExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", -1);
    if (notificationId >= 0) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
    }
}
```

Not ideal, but seems to guarantee a heads-up notification every time, which is the behaviour I want.